# Does mobile apps share cache with each other and with the default browser

Tags: android, ios, caching, mobile, webview

Does Android and iPhone's applications share web content cache with each other and with the default mobile phone browser?

for instant, if I try to open a web page from within the application which was already loaded by the browser or by other application, will it be read from the cache or access the internet?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS the answer is No, applications do not share one web cache, every app has its own web data cache. Cookies also are private in iOS and can not be shared among apps. 
 And Apple has the following info:

> iOS Note: Cookies are not shared among applications in iOS.
>   Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Update: From NSURLSession guid

> Private storage support for caches, cookies, credentials, and
>   protocols in a way that is specific to a single session
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html

Comment: Thanks, though the link refer to cookies not page caching. Do you have a reference to the caching policy (I could not find) because I'm not sure cache and cookies act the same. While cookies would be a violation on privacy sharing static web pages cache could only benefit performance.

Comment: The same thing goes for cache, read this article, scroll to NSURLConnection cache policy http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Comment: one more link to apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy

Comment: Both cache links explain how to work with the cache within one application, but I couldn't find there any things that suggest cross application caching is not working.